# Convert column values separated by comma to a numeric vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame "dfx" like below. I need to convert values in "COUNTY_ID" to a vector to provide to function.

```
dfx:

STATE   COUNTY_ID
KS      15,21,33,101
OH      133,51,12
TX      15,21,37,51,65
```

I have converted the STATE to a vector like below:

```
st = as.vector(as.character(dfx$STATE))
```

But, I need to convert each row in `"COUNTY_ID"` column to a number/numeric vector. For example, `c(15,21,33,101)`

How can I achieve this in R?

Any help is appreciated.

```
cty_id <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(dfx$COUNTY_ID), ","), as.numeric)

DOES NOT work:
mclapply(cty_id[1], FUN = each_cty, st = st[1], mc.cores = detectCores() - 1) 

DOES works: 
mclapply(c(15,21,33,101), FUN = each_cty, st = st[1], mc.cores = detectCores() - 1)
```

Comment: How does the `mclapply` call relate? Seems irrelevant here.

Comment: Idea is to convert each row to a numeric vector to use with mcapply.

Comment: `cty_id[[1]]` instead of `cty_id[1]`

Comment: Thank you. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you want to handle situations like the one in your example data, when KS has four distinct values of county_id, but OH has only three? If you seek to get one column per county_id, and you're ok with missing values in some of the cells, then the easiest thing is to use `stringr::str_split_fixed()`.

```
> result <- stringr::str_split_fixed(dfx$COUNTY_ID, ",", n=5)
> result 
    [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]
[1,] "15"  "21" "33" "101" ""  
[2,] "133" "51" "12" ""    ""  
[3,] "15"  "21" "37" "51"  "65"
```

Note that you need to know the max number of county_ids per row, and put this as an argument `n` above. You can be conservative and just drop columns full of NAs later.

What you get out of this is a matrix of characters. You can then convert it to numeric as follows: `class(result) <- 'numeric'`. After that, each row of the `result` matrix gives you the vector of interest, you may have to wrap it in `na.omit()` to be sure you only get numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
strsplit(as.character(dfx$COUNTY_ID), ",")
#[[1]]
#[1] "15"  "21"  "33"  "101"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "133" "51"  "12"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "15" "21" "37" "51" "65"
```

Explanation: `strsplit(..., ",")` splits every entry based on `","`, and stores the result in a `list` of character vectors.

Or to get a `list` of numeric vectors:

```
lapply(strsplit(as.character(dfx$COUNTY_ID), ","), as.numeric);
#[[1]]
#[1]  15  21  33 101
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 133  51  12
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 15 21 37 51 65
```

Comment: I need to use in mcapply as shown above. I need to provide a vector c(15,21,33,101) using the data frame dfx. When I manually provide mclapply(c(1,3), FUN = each_cty, st = st[2], mc.cores = detectCores() - 1) it works. But, your method still gives me an error.

Comment: I agree with @thelatemail's comment. Not sure what this has to do with `mcapply`. I also don't know what you mean by *"I need to provide a vector c(15,21,33,101) using the data frame "*; I thought you wanted `c(15,21,33,101)` as *output*? If you look at my solution, that's the first element of the `list`.